# Yii CGridview model search using OR ||

Tags: php, search, yii, cgridview

I have created an advanced search form that will search the model using `OR` or `IN` condition. However it fails to update `CGridView` because it returns an array for the attribute of a model. if i remove these columns from the gridview then it will work, but i need these column to be visible on the gridview.

**Model**

```
public function weeklystatus($arr = array())
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        //$criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('PROJECT',$this->PROJECT,true);
        if(!empty($arr) && isset($arr['PROJCODE'])){
            $str = '';
            foreach($arr['PROJCODE'] as $value) {
                $str .= "PROJCODE = '$value' || ";
            }           
            $criteria->addCondition(substr($str, 0, -3));
        }else
            $criteria->compare('PROJCODE',$this->PROJCODE,true);
        $criteria->compare('PROJID',$this->PROJID);
        $criteria->mergeWith($this->dateRangeSearchCriteria('StartDATE', $this->StartDATE));        
        $criteria->mergeWith($this->dateRangeSearchCriteria('ProjectEndDate', $this->ProjectEndDate));
        $criteria->mergeWith($this->dateRangeSearchCriteria('ActualEndDate', $this->ActualEndDate));
        $criteria->compare('PROCESSOR',$this->PROCESSOR,true);
        $criteria->compare('OFFICE',$this->OFFICE,true);
        $criteria->compare('DEPTCODE',$this->DEPTCODE,true);
        //$criteria->compare('PERCENT',$this->PERCENT,true);        
        $criteria->compare('PERCENTPlanned',$this->PERCENTPlanned,true);
        $criteria->compare('KM',$this->KM,true);
        $criteria->compare('KMPlanned',$this->KMPlanned,true);
        if(!empty($arr) && isset($arr['MC'])){
            $str = '';
            foreach($arr['MC'] as $value) {
                $str .= "MC = '$value'";
            }
            $criteria->addCondition($str);
        }else{
            $criteria->compare('MC',$this->MC,true);
        }
        $criteria->compare('MCSALE',$this->MCSALE);
        $criteria->compare('CATEGORY',$this->CATEGORY,true);
        $criteria->compare('AREA',$this->AREA,true);
        $criteria->compare('COUNTRY',$this->COUNTRY,true);
        $criteria->compare('PROJINFO',$this->PROJINFO,true);
        $criteria->compare('REGION',$this->REGION,true);
        $criteria->compare('ASAAREA',$this->ASAAREA,true);
        $criteria->compare('LORM',$this->LORM,true);

        $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-2 week"));
        $criteria->addCondition("StartDATE > '2013-01-01'"); 
        $criteria->addCondition("StartDATE < '$date' AND PERCENT <100 || StartDATE > '$date' AND PERCENT =100 ");
                /*AND (StartDATE < '$date' AND PERCENT <100)
                || (StartDATE > '$date' AND PERCENT =100) ");*/
        //$criteria->addCondition("PERCENT < 100 AND StartDATE < '$date'");
        //$criteria->addCondition('StartDATE > '.$date . ' AND PERCENT >  -1' );

        $criteria->order = 'ASAAREA';


        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
                'pagination'=>array(
                        'pageSize'=>25,
                ),
        ));
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function actionWeeklystatus(){       
        $model=new ViewWebprojectreport('weeklystatus');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        $globalController = new GlobalController;

        if(isset($_GET['ViewWebprojectreport'])){

            $model->attributes=$_GET['ViewWebprojectreport'];
        }

        //print_r($model->attributes);
        //exit();

        $processorList = $globalController->getProcessorList();
        $projCodeList = $globalController->getProjectcodeList();
        $asaarea = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT DISTINCT
                (   view_webprojectreport.ASAAREA   )
                FROM
                view_webprojectreport
                ORDER BY
                view_webprojectreport.ASAAREA ASC")->queryAll();
        $asaareaList = CHtml::listData($asaarea, 'ASAAREA','ASAAREA');
        $officeList = $globalController->getOfficeList();
        $deptCode = $this->getDepartmentCode();
        $deptCodeList = CHtml::listData($deptCode, 'Code','Code');
        $categoryList = $globalController->getCategoryList(array("condition"=>"category_id < 8 || (category_id>8 && category_id < 14) || category_id > 31"));
        $countryList = $globalController->getCountryList();
        $region =Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT DISTINCT
                (   view_webprojectreport.REGION    )
                FROM
                view_webprojectreport
                ORDER BY
                view_webprojectreport.REGION ASC")->queryAll();
        $regionList = CHtml::listData($region, 'REGION','REGION');
        $mcList = array('MC' => "MC","P"=>"Propietary");

        Yii::app()->user->setState('exportModel',$model); //this can be any other storage

        $this->render("weekly_status",array(
                "model"=>$model,    
                'processorList'=>$processorList,
                'asaareaList'=>$asaareaList,
                'projCodeList'=>$projCodeList,
                'officeList'=>$officeList,
                'deptCodeList'=>$deptCodeList,
                'categoryList'=>$categoryList,
                'countryList'=>$countryList,
                'regionList'=>$regionList,
                'mcList'=>$mcList
                ));
    }
```

**View**

```
<?php 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
    $('.search-form').toggle();
    return false;
});

$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('view-weekly-status-grid', {
        data: $(this).serialize(),
    });
    return false;
});

",CClientScript::POS_LOAD);
?>
</head>

<h1>Weekly Status Report</h1>

<div style="font-size: 12pt;">
    <?php //echo CHtml::link('<img src="images/pdficon.gif"/>',array("ViewWebprojectreport/exportToPdf","report"=>"weeklystatus")); ?>
    <?php  echo $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiButton', array(       
          'buttonType'=>'link',
          'name'=>'btnDownloadWeeklyStatus',
          'caption'=>'Download Weekly Status',
          'options'=>array('icons'=>'js:{primary:"ui-icon-document"}'),
            "url"=>"index.php?r=ViewWebprojectreport/exportToPdf&report=weeklystatus",
        'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>"font-size: 12px;height: 30px;"),
            'themeUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/themes',//url of your themes for JUI
        'theme'=>'redmond', //theme name the above url should have a folder named by the theme name specified here eg. /protected/extensions/jui/jquery/css/redmond/
        'cssFile'=>'jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css', // the css file in the theme folder
         ),true); ?>
</div>


<div id="weekly_status_graph" style="height:800px;display:none;width: 1120px;">

</div>



<?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">
<?php  $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
    'model'=>$model,
    'processorList'=>$processorList,
    'asaareaList'=>$asaareaList,
    'projCodeList'=>$projCodeList,
    'officeList'=>$officeList,
    'deptCodeList'=>$deptCodeList,
    'categoryList'=>$categoryList,
    'countryList'=>$countryList,
    'regionList'=>$regionList,
    'mcList'=>$mcList
)); ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->


<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'view-weekly-status-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->weeklystatus(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'rowCssClassExpression'=>'($data->PERCENT == 100)? "yellow" : ($row%2?"even":"odd")',
        //'ajaxUpdate' => TRUE,
        'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'function(id, data){
            $.ajax({
                url: "index.php?r=ViewWebprojectreport/weeklystatusgraph",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "get",
                success: function(data) {
                        if(data.totalprojects>40){
                            $("#weekly_status_graph").css("width","1900px");
                            $("#weekly_status_graph").css("margin-left","-390px");

                        }else if(data.totalprojects>20){        
                            $("#weekly_status_graph").css("width","1250px");
                            $("#weekly_status_graph").css("margin-left","-50px");
                        }else{
                            $("#weekly_status_graph").css("width","1120px");
                            $("#weekly_status_graph").css("margin-left","-0px");
                        }

                        $("#weekly_status_graph").show();
                        buildColumnGraph(data);

                }
            })
        }',
        'columns'=>array(       
                //'MC',
                array(
                        "name"=>"MC",
                        "header"=>"MC/P",
                        "htmlOptions"=>array(
                                "width"=>"20px"
                        )
                ),
                //'OFFICE',
                array(
                        "name"=>"PROJCODE",
                        "header"=>"Center",
                        "htmlOptions"=>array(
                                "width"=>"15px"
                        )
                ),
                //'ASAAREA',
                array(
                        "name"=>"ASAAREA",
                        "header"=>"Region",
                        "htmlOptions"=>array(
                                "width"=>"80px"
                        )
                ),
                //'PROJECT',
                array(
                        "name"=>"PROJECT",
                        "htmlOptions"=>array(
                                "width"=>"150px"
                        )
                ),
                //'LORM',
                array(
                    "name"=>"LORM",
                    "htmlOptions"=>array(
                        "width"=>"20px"
                    )
                ),
                'CATEGORY',
                //'KM',
                array(
                        "name"=>"KM",
                        "header"=>"KM/KM<sup>2</sup>"
                        /*"htmlOptions"=>array(
                                "width"=>"20px"
                        )*/
                ),
                //PROC TYPE
                //'StartDATE',
                array(
                    "name"=>"StartDATE",
                    "htmlOptions"=>array(
                        "width"=>"65px"
                    )
                ),
                //'ProjectEndDate',
                array(
                    "name"=>"ProjectEndDate",
                    "htmlOptions"=>array(
                        "width"=>"65px"
                    )
                ),
                //current date
                /*array(
                    "header"=>"Current date",
                    "value"=>$date
                ),*/
                // planned poc
                // actiaul poc
                //expected
                //'ActualEndDate',
                array(
                    "name"=>"ActualEndDate",
                    "htmlOptions"=>array(
                        "width"=>"65px"
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    "name"=>"PROJINFO",
                    'type'=>'raw',  
                    "value"=>'( strlen($data->PROJINFO) > 200 ) ? CHtml::tag("span", array("title"=>$data->PROJINFO), CHtml::encode(substr($data->PROJINFO, 0, 200)) . "..") : CHtml::encode($data->PROJINFO)',
//                      '$data->GetTruncatedPROJINFO()' ,
                    "htmlOptions"=>array(
                        //"width"=>"300px"
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                    'template'=>'{view}',
                    'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:5px'),
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Say `ASAAREA` I created a check box so i can search the model using 2 condition on 1 column. it returns the results but fails rendering page because I am displaying `ASAAREA` on `CGridView`. How can I resolve this issue?

If I comment out `//'filter'=>$model,` on the view it works fine. But i do not want to do this.

It will produce stack trace if i leave the `filter` uncommented

```
Error 500: <h1>PHP Error [2]</h1>
<p>htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (/opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php:103)</p>
<pre>#0 unknown(0): CWebApplication->handleError()
#1 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php(103): htmlspecialchars()
#2 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php(2610): encode()
#3 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php(158): renderAttributes()
#4 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php(2255): tag()
#5 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php(1434): activeInputField()
#6 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CDataColumn.php(103): activeTextField()
#7 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridColumn.php(116): CDataColumn->renderFilterCellContent()
#8 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridView.php(532): CDataColumn->renderFilterCell()
#9 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridView.php(510): CGridView->renderFilter()
#10 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridView.php(480): CGridView->renderTableHeader()
#11 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php(167): CGridView->renderItems()
#12 unknown(0): CGridView->renderSection()
#13 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php(150): preg_replace_callback()
#14 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php(135): CGridView->renderContent()
#15 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CBaseController.php(173): CGridView->run()
#16 /opt/paradox/protected/views/viewWebprojectreport/weekly_status.php(314): ViewWebprojectreportController->widget()
#17 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CBaseController.php(126): require()
#18 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CBaseController.php(95): ViewWebprojectreportController->renderInternal()
#19 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CController.php(869): ViewWebprojectreportController->renderFile()
#20 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CController.php(782): ViewWebprojectreportController->renderPartial()
#21 /opt/paradox/protected/controllers/ViewWebprojectreportController.php(970): ViewWebprojectreportController->render()
#22 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): ViewWebprojectreportController->actionWeeklystatus()
#23 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams()
#24 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/filters/CFilterChain.php(133): ViewWebprojectreportController->runAction()
#25 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CController.php(291): CFilterChain->run()
#26 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CController.php(265): ViewWebprojectreportController->runActionWithFilters()
#27 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): ViewWebprojectreportController->run()
#28 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController()
#29 /opt/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#30 /opt/paradox/index.php(31): CWebApplication->run()
</pre>
```

Comment: "fails rendering page". Does it produce error?

Comment: @Rafay updated with stack trace

Comment: where are you using arr=array()? I mean where u have used in the weeklyStatus?

Comment: `public function actionWeeklystatus(){` is my action for `view`. `weeklyStatus` is a method in my model which i use to filter the model for certain conditions. This is being used by advanced search and CGridView

Comment: RafayZiaMir the `arr=array()` is for a a report i do which i use in another function. the if statements ignore it so it shouldn't affect. anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display an attribuite of the model that is an array and For example you want to display all the Value in a cell of the grid take into account using clistview. Your Advanced Search Will still work and you ll be able to Write Your custom html For each cell.

another Solution is to render in the cgridview a Virtual variable that serialize Your array attribute

Comment: how would i do the the second method you mentioned?

Comment: Virtual variable is a features of yii. If you Write a function called getMyVar() you Will create the Virtual variable myVar. The Value of MyVar wiil be the Value returned by the function getMyVar(). Now you can use myVar in the widgets as cgridview. Take attention choosing var name, avoid collision with other vars or relations. In other word writing echo $model->myVar is the same of echo $model->getMyVar(). For more info search on google there are lots of documents about yii virtual variable. Tell me if you need more help.